# Azure Automation - Setting user's password with Administrative Unit

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation, azure-security

I need to write an Azure Automation Runbook that sets the password for all Group Members.

The group and the users are a part of an Administrative Unit and the Service Principal is part of a group assigned as Users Administrator for the AU.

When I run `Get-AzureADGroupMember` I get `Authorization_RequestDenied`.

I don't want the service principal to be a Users Administrator for the entire AD.
What permissions do I need for the service principal to be able to both list the users in the group and set their password? How do I set it?

Comment: The `Service Account` here you mean the service principal?

Comment: Yes, I just changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I think this feature should be reasonable, but actually it does not work per my test.

I gave the `Users Administrator` to the service principal at the AU scope, but it cannot reset the user's password in the group belongs to the AU, even cannot reset the direct user's password(the user was directly added in the `Users (Preview)` in the portal).

But if I test with a work account(`xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`) with the same `Users Administrator` at the AU scope, it can reset the direct user's password, but still cannot reset the user's password in the group, looks the permission cannot be inherited.

So in conclusion, if you want to reset the password of the users in the groups belongs to the AU, you need to add these users directly to the `Users (Preview)`, then use a user account e.g. work account with the `Users Administrator` role to do that.

To do this in runbook, you can [store your user name and password in the `Credentials` of the automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials#create-a-new-credential-asset-with-the-azure-portal), then use the code in the runbook to login your account and get group members and reset passwords.

```
$myCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name '<credential-name>'
$userName = $myCred.UserName
$securePassword = $myCred.Password
$myPsCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userName,$securePassword)
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $myPsCred

Get-AzureADGroupMember

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId xxxx -Password $password
```

Comment: I can't run `Connect-AzureAD` with any Work Account because they require MFA,. That's why I'm trying to do so with a Service Principal. It seems like Administrative Unit Role Assignment is ignored for Service Principals but does work when applied for the entire AAD.

Comment: @thecohenoam Yes, the service principal with admin role works fine when the scope is the entire AAD instead of the AU, so in this case, you just have two options, 1. Create a work account without MFA-enabled then use it. 2. Give the admin role to the service principal at the entire AAD scope.

Comment: @thecohenoam Actually, if your requirement is something else without resetting passwords, you can directly give the Application Graph API permission for the AD App, but the operation to reset password is special, it needs the Delegated permission which is not available in Application permission, it does not apply to the case logged with service principal.